# Randomly select a line in every block of N lines

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, shuf

I'd like to randomly select a line after a given number of lines. For example here's my input:

```
8 blue
8 red
8 yellow
8 orange
3 pink
3 white
3 cyan
3 purple
1 magenta
1 black
1 green
1 brown
```

and with random selection a line from every four lines, my output would be:

```
8 orange
3 pink
1 green
```

The best I've come up with is:

```
awk '!(NR%4){a=NR+4};NR<=a|"shuf -n 1"'
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: elaborate why `3 pink` should be selected?

Comment: because that's from the next set of 4 lines. I want to iterate through the file, 4 lines at a time, picking a random line at each set of 4 lines

Answer (score 4):

With the GNU implementation of the **`split`** command:

```
split -l 4 --filter='shuf -n1' inputfile
```

- `-l N` - put `N` lines/records per output file
- `--filter=COMMAND` - write to shell `COMMAND`; file name is `$FILE`

Comment: works like a champ thank you! I didn't know about split

Answer (score 2):

To select p=1 line out of every n=4 lines at random:

```
awk -v n=1000 -v p=50 '
  BEGIN {srand(); remaining = p}
  NR > n {remaining = p; NR = 1}
  rand()*(n + 1 - NR) < remaining {
    print; remaining--
  }' < your-file
```

To have `awk` invoke GNU `shuf` every 4 lines, you'd need:

```
awk -v cmd="shuf -n 1" '{print | cmd}; NR % 4 == 0 {close(cmd)}'
```

But that means running one `sh` and one `shuf` command every 4 lines of the file which is a lot less efficient.